# PHP+Javascript upload based on sessions not working

Tags: php, javascript, session

I'm using lighttpd + PHP 5.4 running with FastCGI on buildroot embedded linux.
I have written some time ago a modified version of PHP file upload progress script using following tutorial: http://phpmaster.com/tracking-upload-progress-with-php-and-javascript/
I was previously working on Slackware Apache with mod_php and everything worked fine.

Unfortunately, the script is not working. I have made sure that in php.ini `session.upload_progress = On` and sessions are enabled. I have verified that sessions are working in general by using two simple php files as in 4. post here http://quirm.net/forum/topic.php?id=3950.

The script is supposed to show loading screen and percentage of file upload. It is achieved by sending `progress.php` requests every 0.2 second. Unfortunately, no matter how large is the file (I use ~13 MB files for testing, I have ensured that the file upload size in php.ini accepts this size) the upload ends after first request because it returns 100. I have debbuged progress.php and it looks that the whole $_SESSION variable is empty.

Here is my form HTML code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="actions/upload_upgrade.php" method="post" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="upload_type='config'; startUpload('config_form')" id="config_form">
                <p class="stdtext">
                Select File:
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="config">
                <input type="hidden" value="config_form"
                name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>">
                <input type="file" size="35" name="userfile" />
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" class="defaultbtn" name="Upload" value="Upload" onclick="showLoadingScreen(true)"/>
                </p>
            </form>
```

My Javascript code (please note that upload and response handling functions are made universal because they accept uploads from several different forms that are used to upload configuration, firmware etc.).

```
function sendUploadRequest(form_name)
{
    job_name="Upload";
    var http = createRequestObject();
    http.open("GET", "actions/progress.php?form_name="+form_name);
    http.onreadystatechange = function () { handleResponse(http,"sendUploadRequest('"+form_name+"')"); };
    http.send(null);
}

function startUpload(form_name)
{
    showLoadingScreen(true);
    postDataSync("actions/uw.php");
    document.getElementById("loadingtext").innerHTML="Uploading file...";
    setTimeout("sendUploadRequest('"+form_name+"')", 200);
}

function handleResponse(http,fun_name)
{
    hideInfo();
    var response;
    if (http.readyState == 4) 
    {
        response = http.responseText;
        document.getElementById("loadingtext").innerHTML = response + "%";

        if (response < 100)
        {
            setTimeout(fun_name, 200);
        }
        else
        {
            showLoadingScreen(false);
            if(job_name=="")
                printInfo("Job completed successfuly");
            else
            {
                if(job_name=="Upload"&&upload_type=="config")
                {
                    if(hidden_iframe.window.document.body.innerHTML=="SUCCESS")
                    {
                        printInfo(job_name+" completed successfuly");
                        showLoadingScreen(true);
                        document.getElementById("loadingtext").innerHTML="Restoring backup...";
                        var result=postDataSync("actions/extract_backup.php");
                        showLoadingScreen(false);
                        if(result.substring(0,5)=="ERROR")
                        {
                            printError("Error while extracting backup configuration:<br><br>"+result.substring(6));
                        }
                        else if(result.substring(0,7)=="SUCCESS")
                        {
                            printInfo("Backup configuration restored successfully");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printError("Unknown error while extracting backup. Please contact service.");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printInfo(job_name+" was not completed because of errors");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(hidden_iframe.window.document.body.innerHTML=="SUCCESS")
                        printInfo(job_name+" completed successfuly");
                    else
                        printError(job_name+" was not completed because of errors");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function createRequestObject()
{
    var http;
    if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    {
        http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else
    {
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return http;
}
```

And my PHP code **progress.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
//print_r($_SESSION);
$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . $_GET['form_name'];
if (!empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
    $current = $_SESSION[$key]["bytes_processed"];
    $total = $_SESSION[$key]["content_length"];
    echo $current < $total ? ceil($current / $total * 100) : 100;
}
else {
    echo 100;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any call of `session_start()`

Comment: start the session_start()

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited my post to include session_start() in progress.php. I have removed it at some point while debugging. Unfortunately, that's not an issue. I used print_r for printing out whole session contents and checked the response in firebug-the $_SESSION is an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On http://de3.php.net/manual/de/session.upload-progress.php it's said: "Note, this feature doesn't work, when your webserver is runnig PHP via FastCGI."